# Horizontal movement on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

What would be the best way to *exactly* recreate this effect?

https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q9_hg7osQ9w

So far I was able to move the top line, but I find it very difficult (if not impossible) to combine this with the bottom line and the fading animation.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
var window_width = $(window).width() - $('.top-line').width();

var document_height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
        var object_position_right = window_width * (scroll_position / document_height);
        $('.top-line').css({
            'right': object_position_right
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure the element    `top-line` 's position attribute is set to fixed or relative but not static!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but I made a quick pen with a similar animation like the one shown in the video: https://codepen.io/adamk22/pen/vVrLYz

JS:

```
var topTitle = $('.top-title'),
    bottomTitle = $('.bottom-title');

var fadeStart = 10,
    fadeUntil = 200,
    moveSpeed = 2; // Higher = slower


$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        opacity = 0,
        topTitlePos = scrollTop / moveSpeed + 'px',
        bottomTitlePos = scrollTop / moveSpeed + 'px';

    if (scrollTop <= fadeStart ) {
        opacity = 1;
    } else if ( scrollTop <= fadeUntil ) {
        opacity = 1 - scrollTop / fadeUntil;
    }

    topTitle.css({'transform': 'translateX(' + topTitlePos + ')', 'opacity': opacity});
    bottomTitle.css({'transform': 'translateX(-' + bottomTitlePos + ')', 'opacity': opacity});
});
```

Obviously, depending on the use-case there may be better ways to write it, but hopefully the pen helps you at least understand what it does and why it works.

Also, when animating elements using js/jquery, try to avoid using properties such as `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` due to performance issues. Use `transform` instead, e.g. `transform: translateX(100px);`. Check out this article for details: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/